# Git Workflows: do you need to keep your working directory and remote branch directory separate on your computer?

Tags: wordpress, git, github, git-branch, gitlab

I am fairly new to git, So apologize for being vague.

So I am working on a local folder "MyWorkingDirectory" do I keep push the same folder to my git or copy all the changes manually to a new folder where I manage my remote branch and push from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we would have just one folder under git control locally, and push changes from there to the remote (github perhaps).

Copying files manually kind of defeats the purpose of Git.

If you need to keep code you are working on separate from code which is being deployed, then you should use branches:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

Git can be a little intimidating to begin with, but just learn how to use 'init', 'add', 'commit', 'push' and 'pull'. This will cover 90% of what you will use

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to copy files to new folder to push. With modern version control systems such as Git you can

- switch between branches inside working are; Git will update changed files as necessary (better do this in clean state, without unsaved changes; though Git tries to preserve them, in some rare cases you might lose your uncommitted work)
- push branch other than the current one by specifying a branch to push, e.g. `git push origin new-feature`, and even specifying the branch to push to e.g. `git push origin HEAD:new-feature`
- examine history on remote branches without checking them, e.g. `git log origin/master`.